# Call c++ function from assembly

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I have this assembly file

```
bits 32
global _start
extern kmain

section .text
_start:
    cli
    call kmain
    hlt
```

And this .cpp file

```cpp
void kmain(void)
{    
}
```

And when running these commands:

```
nasm -f elf32 asmfoo.asm -o asmfoo.o
gcc -m32 -c cppfoo.cpp -o cppfoo.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T ./linker.ld -o foo-output asmfoo.o cppfoo.o
```

I get this error:

```
ld: asmfoo.o: in function `_start':
asmfoo.asm:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `kmain'
```

But when I change the name of the cpp file from cppfoo.cpp to cppfoo.c and run the same compile commands it works without any errors.
So how would I call a c++ function from assembly as this doesent work with c++ for some reason.

Comment: You’ll need to either use `extern “C”` to disable mangling, or you’ll have to call the actual mangled function name. C++ includes parameter info etc in the function name, C doesn’t. You can use `nm` command to list the functions in the object file you compiled from C++ code to see the naming

Comment: As for the mangling, the specifics depend on the OS in use.  For ELF targets, I believe the mangling is documented in the SysV ABI document.

Comment: Thank I got it working now! I didn't know about the name mangling before but now I know so thanks once again!